# Using remaining space on a startup disk

Tags: boot, startup, disk, dd

While using applications like dd, Startup disk creater, etcher I can see that a lot of space on the startup disk is unusable. This is normally equal to the diskspace minus the ISO size.

How can this be used?

I wanted to make a USB with clonezilla live and the image. This way I can restore my installation by just using the USB drive.

Comment: For me, the space _is_ usable - I can copy files onto my USB drive, and for e.g. my 16GB one, I have 13.5GB of usable free space remaining. However, I'm using the startup disk creator which came with Ubuntu 14.04 - perhaps the newer one is different in this respect ? IIRC, this is _not_ the case when using `dd` to write the image - `dd` leaves no usable free space. However, what you could try is to unpack the Clonezilla ISO (there are various tools for this), add the image to it, put the ISO back together, and write to the USB stick.